# batch file gpg command

Tags: batch-file, gnupg

I want to encrypt files using GnuPG. I have written a .bat file to do that. The contents of the bat file is like

```
gpg --trust-model always --recipient aaa@yyy.com --encrypt File_name
```

when the file i want to encrypt is on my local machine this works fine. 
but what i want is to encrypt a file that is on a shared path (without copying to my local machine). when i give the File_name as \\shared_path\File_name i get gpg: file not found error.
Any sort of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps gpg cannot handle UNC paths. Try using PUSHD to temporarily change your directory to the UNC path

```
pushd \\shared_path
gpg ...
popd
```